# APK Takes long time to start in the first time

Tags: android, apk, tablet

We have developed an APK Application running on tablets. In this application we have created various csv files and by reading these csv files, the apk creates database(sqllite) files when running for the first time. This database file is used in the application in various dropdowns(masters in other keywords). I am facing a very serious issue in this. We have a csv file of around 12000 rows in it and because of this the apk takes around 1 hour for the first time. By first time, I meant when I install the apk on tablet and run it for the first time. This is becoming a very serious issue in my application and I need to resolve this. Can anyone give any idea how to overcome this.

Comment: 12 000 rows should **not** take an hour to process

Comment: You need to take time to understand exactly what your initialization process is doing, and why it is so inefficient.  While quite portable, csv files are a relatively primitive form of database, and may not be the best choice for use inside the app - though retaining support for import/export is great.

Answer (score 0):

You should try preprocess the SQL database using an Android emulator/device running a special version of your app, put the result DB in your release APK, and simply copy the DB over to the appropriate place during application's first run. The process of retrieving the DB from Android emulator/device can be found [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Comment: Try what @kai has answered.. Thats the best approach to ship your app with pre populated db. Try to find what is causing the database creation/insertion to be so slow by logging at different steps ..

Comment: The thing here is that we also have given an option of updating the csv files later on if there is any change in value. While updating any of the csv files, these database files are deleted and then recreated. Will the pre created db help in this regard?? Plz help

Comment: In this process, instead of updating the CSV files, you update the DB files, so no flexibility is lost. From what I understand, these CSV files are just intermediaries that you use to create DBs, but on resource constrained mobile devices it's better to skip as many intermediaries as possible.